# Google Is Not Defined

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a simple app that looks up a Place, but I'm getting a ReferenceError when I try to run it.  My current code is taken straight from a Google tutorial, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

```
function myFunction()
{
  var map;
  var service;
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: pyrmont,
      zoom: 15
      });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '500',
    types: ['store']
    };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.search(request, callback);
}
```

The error I get is "ReferenceError: "google" is not defined." on this line

```
var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316);
```

I assume its something simple like some sort of include, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: Talk about sensationalist titles.

Comment: I ran the google code specified here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places

And did not see any reference errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Apps Script is not the same as Javascript. 
The code you are writing here is for the JavaScript API of Google Maps. To use Maps in Apps Script, use the classes defined in the Apps Script documentation - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_maps

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  So, is there a way to access the Places API from within Google App Script?  My end goal is to find a business by name and zipcode and extract the phone number.  I would like the source of my data to be a Google Spreadsheet, thats why I went with Google App Script.  Am I headed in the wrong direction?

Comment: You can use the Places API https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/ with Google Apps Script using UrlFetch.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#loading_the_library) :

The Places service is a self-contained library, separate from the main Maps API JavaScript code. To use the functionality contained within this library, you must first load it using the libraries parameter in the Maps API bootstrap URL:

See the [Libraries Overview](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries) for more information.

+1 to Srik Answer : this is indeed not about Google Apps Script